# Why Object[].class.isAssignableFrom(String[].class) == true?

Tags: java, arrays, jvm

Why is `Object[].class.isAssignableFrom(String[].class) == true`, while `String[].getSuperClass()` or `getGenericInterfaces()` could not get `Object[]`?

I checked the source of JDK, but i don't think i can get the answer myself.
For now, I know JDK uses tree to store the relationship between Classes, and depth to indicate its level, `Class::isAssignableFrom()` searched the chain, so definately arrays are in that tree. and also `String[]` is connected to `Object[]`.

Can i say that `String[]` is a subclass of `Object[]`?
Or is it just another weird thing of Java?

Answer (score 6):

[`Class.isAssignableFrom()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) essentially checks the [subtyping relation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.10). "subtype" and "subclass" are two different concepts. The class hierarchy (i.e. subclassing) is only a part of subtyping.

[Primitive types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.10.1) and [array types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.10.3) have special cases for subtyping.

The rules for subtyping of array types are like this (note that "><sub>1</sub>" means "is a directy subtype of"):

> - If `S` and `T` are both reference types, then `S[]` ><sub>1</sub> `T[]` iff `S` ><sub>1</sub> `T`.
> - `Object` ><sub>1</sub> `Object[]`
> - `Cloneable` ><sub>1</sub> `Object[]`
> - `java.io.Serializable` ><sub>1</sub> `Object[]`
> - If `p` is a primitive type, then:
>
>   - `Object` ><sub>1</sub> `p[]`
>   - `Cloneable` ><sub>1</sub> `p[]`
>   - `java.io.Serializable` ><sub>1</sub> `p[]`

The important part for your question is the very first item: an array type `X[]` is a subtype of an array type `Y[]` if and only if the component type `X` is a subtype of the component type `Y`.

Also note that strictly speaking neither `Object[]` nor `String[]` are classes. They are "only" types. While every class implicitly is a type, the reverse is not true. Another example of types that are not classes are the primitive types: `boolean`, `byte`, `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float` and `double` are types, but they are *not* classes.

Another cause for confusion is the fact that you can easily get `java.lang.Class` objects representing those *types*. Again: This does *not* mean that those types are classes.

Comment: wow, where did you get the rules? can you give me a link? it seems String[] is subclass of Object[]. thank you a lot

Comment: No, String[] +is not a subclass+ of Object[]! That's what I'm saying all the time! It's a +subtype+, but that's a dfferent thing! I've had the links to the rules in my answer all the time, btw.

Answer (score 2):

In Java (and .NET), arrays are covariant. It means you can pass an instance of type `Apple[]` to a method that expects a `Fruit[]` if `Apple` inherits `Fruit`. The following line is valid:

```
Fruit[] fruits = apples; // apples is an Apple[]
```

This means a `Fruit[]` is assignable from `Apple[]`.

This is not very safe, of course. Assume:

```
void someMethod(Object[] objects) {
    objects[0] = "Hello World"; // throws at run time.
}

void test() {
    Integer[] integers = new Integer[10];
    integers[0] = 42;
    someMethod(integers); // compiles fine.
}
```

This design decision is handy when you want to use arrays contents (e.g. print it) but not modify it.

Comment: The code you showed will throw an `ArrayStoreException` at runtime!

Comment: ... or modify it based on objects of the base type, the purpose of polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Because `String[]` can actually be converted/widened to `Object[]`.

You might be thinking that this tests if `String[]` is assignable from `Object[]`, [but it actually](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) tests the reverse (if `String[]` can be assigned *to* `Object[]`).

This code compiles and executes as expected:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strings = new String[]{ "hello", "world" };
    printArray(strings);
}

public static void printArray(Object[] array) {
    for (Object obj : array) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If *this* object represents an array class then the Class object representing the Object class is returned.[link](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass())