# Why Collection.toArray(T[]) doesn't take an E[] instead

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

The `toArray` method (lets pick the implementation in [`java.util.ArrayList`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html)) is the following:

```
class ArrayList<E> ....{
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a){
        if(a.length < size)
            return (T[]) Arrays.copyof(elementData, size, a.getClass());
        System.arraycopy(elementData, 0, a, 0, size);
        if(a.length > size)
            a[size] = null;
        return a;
    }    
}
```

I am wondering could we use `<E>` instead of `<T>` in this case ? like

```
public E[] toArray(E[] a){
      if(a.length < size)
             return (E[]) Arrays.copyof(elementData, size, a.getClass());
      System.arraycopy(elementData, 0, a, 0, size);
      if(a.length > size)
            a[size] = null;
      return a;
}
```

Since the ArrayList class iteself is already generic to `<E>`, so could we use that instead of a new generic type `<T>` ?

Comment: what do you mean *we* could use `<E>` instead of `T` - ?  Are you asking why `ArrayList<E>.toArray()` is defined like that ? or you are asking that while using an instance of an `ArrayList` why cant we automatically imply the `E` in the `toArray()` ?

Comment: People always seem to ask about `toArray` with respect to `ArrayList`, but that method is actually [declared by `Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray\(T[]\)).

Comment: Yes you are right let me update the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of the `<T>` is if the array desired is of a base class of `E`. For example if `E` is `HashMap` but the desired array was `Map[]`. If `toArray` were locked down to `E` this would not be possible.

This type of thing is not needed in generic collections / types due to type-erasure. But there is no type-erasure with arrays so the type of the array can be very important.

Comment: What do you mean by your first sentence ?

Comment: Take `Integer`, it extends `Number`. If you had a `List<Integer>` but needed to convert it to a `Number[]`, having the type returned by `toArray` be `T` would limit it to only returning `Integer[]`. The current signature allows it to return any type to which `Integer` can be cast (Number, Comparable, etc).

Comment: So the purpose of using a separate generic type T is mainly for preventing that ?

Comment: I think you got E and T reversed. But anyway, the way that the method is declared, the two type variables have no constraint with one another. So you could ask for an array of *any type* (not just a supertype). I guess this is okay since arrays are checked at runtime, and your elements might really be of that type. But it means less compile-time checks than you think.

Comment: Arrays are already covariant. `(Number[]) new Integer[0]` is valid. If `T` had to be a super class of `E`, it would use a `super` bound i.e. `T super E`.

Answer (score 12):

I think [John B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12356004/697449) covered the idea well - I'd just like to elaborate on it a little.

First, let's look at the method signature you proposed in your question:

```
public E[] toArray(E[] a)
```

As John explained, this signature is less flexible. If I want to dump an `ArrayList<Integer>` into a `Number[]`, this method doesn't let me. The Collections API wants to allow that flexibility.

Unfortunately the method as it stands doesn't allow for compile-time checking on the type of the array, which is the issue you seem to be getting at. The documentation for [`toArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29), which is declared by the `Collection`, explains that an `ArrayStoreException` may be thrown "if the runtime type of the specified array is not a supertype of the runtime type of every element in this collection".

Based on that description, it *seems* like the following signature would be ideal:

```
public <T super E> T[] toArray(T[] a)
```

At first glance, this seems like it would allow any legal type of array to be passed in and populated - but would provide type checking at compile time instead of run time. So why is this signature not declared instead?

Well, this syntax:

```
 <T super E>
```

is [not supported by the language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2800369/697449). But it's easy for that to distract you from the fact that this type checking wouldn't work anyway. The problem is that unlike parameterized types, [arrays are covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1650931/697449). An `Integer[]` is a `Number[]` is an `Object[]`. So given our hypothetical signature with `<T super E>`, if I called `toArray` on an `ArrayList<Number>` and passed in an `Integer[]`, it would still compile - and possibly fail at runtime depending on what was in the list.

So the bottom line is, a lower bound on the component type of the array passed in isn't going to do any good.

Comment: I think you mean "if I called `toArray` on an `ArrayList<Integer>` and passed in an `Number[]`" because `Number` is a super type of `Integer`. Aside from that, I am having trouble following. Can you provide an example of an `ArrayList<Integer>` where `toArray` into a `Number[]` fails at runtime?

Comment: @DanielTrebbien Thanks for asking. I meant exactly what I wrote, as an example of something that *seems* like it wouldn't compile, until you remember that an `Integer[]` is also a `Number[]` due to array covariance. It's a hypothetical example in which we pretend the syntax `<T super E>` is legal (it isn't).

Comment: @DanielTrebbien As for the example you asked for, consider that a `Long[]` is also a `Number[]`. So I could call `toArray` on an `ArrayList<Integer>` and pass in a `Long[]` - it would compile but fail at runtime with an `ArrayStoreException`.