# Why <T> for toArray hides <E> of Collection<E>?

Tags: java, generics, collections

`toArray` method hides `<E>` passed to `Collection<E>` interface. Below is the method signature.

```
<T> T[] toArray(T[] a);
```

Because of which below is possible. And results into `ArrayStoreException`

```
ArrayList<String> string = new ArrayList<String>();
string.add("1");
string.add("2");
Integer intArray[] = new Integer[2];
intArray = string.toArray(intArray);
```

I wanted to know why was such decision taken? Why was such a case allowed while designing the API ? As anyway this code results in to `RuntimeException`?

Comment: Make your question a little bit clearer.

Comment: As I understand, your question is, why not use the type passed to ArrayLists type parameter, is this correct?

Comment: @M.M. There is no relation between type passed and to type being used in toArray method. I wanted to know why such a decision is taken.

Comment: Good question, but it's been covered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355941/collection-toarray-generic-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `toArray` method predates the introduction of generics.  The original signature of `toArray` took an arbitrary `Object[]`.

This is the only way, with generics, to accept the same input that was permissible before generics.  However, the advantage of taking an arbitrary `T[]` is that it can return the same array type that it's passed.

Comment: There is also good explanation on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355941/collection-toarray-generic-method) thread. I hope I could have accepted both answers :)

Comment: I don't really agree with this argument. If they took the pre-generics code and didn't change it, it would still work, because you would have a raw `ArrayList`, so its `toArray` would take `Object[]`.

Comment: There are still a couple more funky edge cases I can think of -- for example, if you had a `class FooList extends ArrayList<Foo>`, and you had the `toArray` method take only a `T[]`, then that one would take only a `Foo[]`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call, `intArray = string.toArray(intArray);`, you are expecting it to construct Array of `Integer` and return the values and hence the return type is `T[]` i.e. `Integer[]` in your case.

Calling the method like that doesn't mean you would be able to automatically convert String list into `Integer []`. The above method invocation will result into `java.lang.ArrayStoreException`.

**This is done to allow usage of convertible classes(base class/subclass)** e.g. below:

```
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  list.add(1);

  Integer[] intArray = new Integer[1];
  intArray = list.toArray(intArray); //Success

  Number [] numArray = new Number[1];
  numArray = list.toArray(numArray);//Success

  Double [] dubArray = new Double[1];
  dubArray = list.toArray(dubArray); //Failure(ArrayStoreException)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you ask yourself what should be the type of the array in `toArray()`, the first, most obvious way is to restrict `T` to be a supertype of `E` (which includes if `T` is the same as `E`): This makes sense -- to be able to copy the elements to an array of a more general element type than our collection. However, although this seems type-safe (i.e. checked at compile time so that no exceptions occur at runtime) at first glance, it is not completely type-safe -- a variable of type `T[]` can hold any array of type `U[]` where `U` is a subtype of `T`. Thus, it is still possible to get an `ArrayStoreException` even if we limit `T` to supertypes of `E` (and, *even* if we limit `T` to be the same as `E`). Plus, it is difficult to declare this method in such a way that `T` can only be a supertype of `E`, since Java does not allow `super` bounds for type parameters.

The example in the question involves a `T` that is not a supertype of `E`. Why should this be allowed? This is not type-safe, and will work only if the elements of the collection are actually subtypes of the actual type of the array. However, it can be argued that this is still *no worse* than the situation where we restrict `T` to a supertype of `E`, or even if we have `T` be the same as `E`, because, as explained above, none of those restrictions can make it type-safe either. It's possible to get `ArrayStoreException` no matter how you declare this method. So why not make it as general as possible, if it's no worse?

Answer (score -1):

`string.toArray(intArray)` returns an array of type `String`; howver, you desire it to be an array of type `Integer`. This is going to return the exception you mention, `ArrayStoreException` due to the types not matching.