# Confused about `toArray(T[] a)` method in java

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

The `List` has a method `toArray` such as:

```
<T> T[] java.util.ArrayList.toArray(T[] a)
```

When calling this method, I should create a new instance and pass it `toArray(new MyElementClass[0])`.

Could it be defined like this:

```
<T> T[] java.util.ArrayList.toArray(Class<T>)
```

By calling `toArray(MyElementClass[].class)`, can it be more effective?

Comment: Probably yes, although you could always keep a number of constants with zero-length arrays of each of the types that you need. But the question is very hypothetical, since you can't change the API classes.

Comment: It would have to be `Class<T>` rather than `Class<?>`.

Comment: List is interface and it does not have method called "toArray". There is implementation of this interface called ArrayList which does. Just to not confuse other people

Comment: If it was `<T> T[] toArray(Class<T>)`, then you would have to call it as `toArray(MyElementClass.class)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be. However, the original method is given for backwards compatibility.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422161/java-list-t-t-toarrayt-a-implementation)

Answer (score 1):

The way `toArray` is now, it allows you to re-use an array (it will use the given array if it is of sufficient size) rather than always needing to allocate a new one.