# Java error when passing in generic method parameter

Tags: java, generics, lambda, method-reference

```
public static class MyClass {
    public String methodS(UnaryOperator<String> fn) {
        return fn.apply("");
    }
    public Integer methodI(UnaryOperator<Integer> fn) {
        return fn.apply(0);
    }
    public <T> T identity(T t) {
        return t;
    }
    public <T> void test(UnaryOperator<T> fn) {
        String s;
        s = methodS(UnaryOperator.identity()); // OK
        s = methodS(this::identity);           // OK
        s = methodS(String::trim);             // OK
        s = methodS(fn::apply);                // Fail
        Integer i;
        i = methodI(UnaryOperator.identity()); // OK
        i = methodI(this::identity);           // OK
        i = methodI(Math::abs);                // OK
        i = methodI(fn::apply);                // Fail
    }
    public void goal() {
        test(o -> {
            doSomething(o);
            return o;
        });
    }
}
```

I wonder why passing class method references OK but passing a method parameter not in the above example? How do you fix it?

The goal is to be able to call like in the `goal()` method, where a generic lambda can be written to take on the common base class object (in this case `Object`).

---

Edited: some misunderstood the question, probably because of `Object` as the base class. Here might be a better example with some custom common base class:

```
public static class MyClass {
    public static class ExtS extends MyClass {};
    public static class ExtI extends MyClass {};
    public void common() {}
    public ExtS methodS(UnaryOperator<ExtS> fn) {
        return fn.apply(new ExtS());
    }
    public ExtI methodI(UnaryOperator<ExtI> fn) {
        return fn.apply(new ExtI());
    }
    public <X extends MyClass> X identity(X x) {
        x.common(); // can call MyClass methods
        return x;
    }
    public <Y extends MyClass> void test(UnaryOperator<Y> fn) {
        ExtS s;
        s = methodS(UnaryOperator.identity());    // OK
        s = methodS(this::identity);              // OK
        s = methodS(t -> (ExtS) fn.apply((Y) t)); // OK
        s = methodS(fn::apply);                   // fail
        ExtI i;
        i = methodI(UnaryOperator.identity());    // OK
        i = methodI(this::identity);              // OK
        i = methodI(t -> (ExtI) fn.apply((Y) t)); // OK
        i = methodI(fn::apply);                   // fail
    }
    public void goal() {
        test(y -> {
            y.common(); // can call MyClass methods
            return y;
        });
        test(this::identity); // doing the same as above
    }
}
```

Comment: `fn::apply` returns a `T` (not a `String` or an `Integer`). Simple as that. If you want a `String` you need a `UnaryOperator<String> fn` (and for an `Integer` you would need a `UnaryOperator<Integer>`).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks, but then how would you explain `identity`? Its also just taking `T` and returning `T`.

Comment: Someone can call `test(String::trim)`. What would `methodI(fn::apply);` do in that case? The type would be incorrect. You cannot make a similar argument for `this::identity`.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes I am aware, but I can argue this is also stopping me from calling `test(this::identity)` as well, which should be possible.

Comment: Do you realise that the `T` in the declaration of `test` is a *different* type from the `T` in the declaration of `identity`?

Comment: @Sweeper No I don't, that's why I am asking this question. Could you please answer it if you know why? Thank you.

Comment: Okay, I will tell you that they are actually different types. They are different because they are type parameters of different methods. Does that answer “why”? If not, please clarify what you mean by “why”.

Comment: @Sweeper No, not really. As far as I concern, firstly `UnaryOperator.identity()` returns a `UnaryOperator<T>`. Secondly, `this::identity` also takes in `T` and returns `T`. I have no clue how the method parameter `UnaryOperator<T>` is any difference? Especially comparing to `UnaryOperator.identity()`, which is more an apple to apple comparison.

Comment: Your goal is impossible to achieve. There is no syntax to declare that `T` must be a common supertype of `Integer` and `String`.

Comment: @Holger Thanks. But its possible by doing specific cast. e.g. `methodS(t -> (String) fn.apply((T) t)); methodI(t -> (Integer) fn.apply((T) t));` Or I can put `doSomething(o)` inside `identity(T t)`. So I still wonder why?

Comment: What is “it” in “it’s possible”? You still can’t declare that `T` must be a common supertype of `Integer` and `String`. You added type casts to make the code run, regardless of what `T` is, but can fail with a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

Comment: @Holger It is the goal, as stated in the question, to be able to write a lambda to operate on the common base class object. But the mystery still remains "why" `this::identity` works? As in `t` is the common base class object there and no type cast is needed.

Comment: As said by others, the type parameter declared by `identity` is entirely unrelated to the type parameter declared by `test`. Don’t get confused just because they both are named `T`. Use `public <X> X identity(X x) { return x; } public <O> void test(UnaryOperator<O> fn) { … }` if it helps you better understanding that these type parameters are unrelated. You want `O` to be a common supertype while the `identity` method doesn’t care what `X` is. In `methodS(this::identity)`, `X` will be `String` and in `methodI(this::identity)`, `X` will be `Integer`. But you can’t change `O` inside `test`.

Comment: @Holger I bet you misunderstood me, I am not confused by the letter `T`. I've updated the question, hopefully with a better illustration. Here both inside `identity(X x)` and the lambda `y -> {...}`, they can both call the common base class methods. So I really find no difference between `<X extends MyClass> X identity(X x)` and `<Y extends MyClass> UnaryOperator<Y> fn`, but Java allows `this::identity` but not `fn::apply` to be passed to `methodS`/`methodI`, thats my question.

Comment: Why would you expect it to work? fn::apply is a UnaryOperator that takes a Y. That Y is a subclass of MyClass. methodI requires a UnaryOperator that is a *specific subclass of MyClass* namely ExtI.

Comment: As already said, `methodS(this::identity)` decides that `X` will be `String` for this particular use case and `methodI(this::identity)` decides that `X` will be `Integer` for this particular, independent use case. Neither of these two use cases is related to `Y`. The `test` method declares a type parameter `Y`, leaving it to the code using `test` to decide what `Y` will be. `<Y extends MyClass>` isn’t even a “common base type of `ExtI` or `ExtS`” but an arbitrary subtype of `MyClass`. E.g., you can pass a `UnaryOperator<ExtI>` to `test`, how is that supposed to work with `methodS(fn::apply)`?

Comment: Maybe, the problem is that you are thinking that every `UnaryOperator` has to be some sort of identity function. See [this demonstration](https://ideone.com/HVhqQW) of some legal callers of `test`, then think about how passing those functions to `methodS` or `methodI` is supposed to work.

Comment: @Holger This is going in circles. Allow me to follow your train of thought, so given `fn::apply` won't work, could you explain why `this::identity` works? For all I see they both defined a. a generic type parameter b. both extend from `MyClass` c. both take it as input d. both return it. My question is what tells them apart that causes one fails but the other works?

Comment: @matt yes I can see thats not working , so then my question is why `this::identity` works for they have seemingly the same definition minus the difference that I can't tell, hence this question.

Comment: Only you are moving in circles by asking the same question over and over again, ignoring every explanation given. The method `apply` does *not* declare a type parameter. It’s fundamentally different to a generic method like `identity`.

Comment: @Holger Of course it is the same question because I do not understand. If we look into `UnaryOperator#apply`, it is defined as `Y apply(Y y)` and my `Y` is `<Y extends MyClass>`, which I can't tell the difference from `<X extends MyClass> X identity(X x)`. Forget about the programming logic for a minute if you will, I ask from the syntax perspective, where is the difference that is not expressing the same intention between them?

Comment: Do you notice that there is no “`<Y>`” in `Y apply(Y y)`? This method does *not* declare a type parameter—it uses an existing type parameter (from the `UnaryOperator` type). This method is not generic. In contrast, `<X extends MyClass> X identity(X x)` *does* declare a type parameter; this is a generic method. Fundamentally different.

Comment: @Holger Yeah, thanks so much. Combined with what @matt said, am I correct to say `<Y>` defined for the interface is fixed, while `<X>` defined for the method is adaptive? And there is no syntax to define an adaptive type parameter for interface/class in Java?

Comment: The type *is* adaptive and your declaration `<Y extends MyClass> void test(UnaryOperator<Y> fn)` allows to choose a type argument for `Y`, however, it’s the *caller of `test`* who chooses what `Y` is. You can’t choose the method signature of `fn::apply` inside the `test` method because the caller already did. You still can create arbitrarily typed `UnaryOperator`s inside the method; the type is as generic as the method `identity`is. The crucial point is who chooses the actual type arguments for a particular generic construct. For the `fn` parameter, it’s the caller of the method.

Comment: @Holger Hey, I guess what you said in this comment _is the answer_ that I finally understand and explained the reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should step back and try doing actual assignments. When you try to do `methodI` all you are doing is assigning the argument to `UnaryOperator<ExI>`.

```
static <T> UnaryOperator<T> identity()
```

That means the T is assigned when you call identity.

```
methodI(UnaryOperator::identity);
```

This is good, that is the point of the identity, you call it with an argument and it will take that generic. When you call `methodI` it assigns the generic of UnaryOperator.identity as `ExtI`.

```
methodI(this::identity);
```

Same as the previous example, it takes the type when you call identity so the type is not defined until you assign it in the argument of methodI.

```
methodI(fn::apply);
```

This is not good because **you have already assigned the type of fn**. It is `Y` all you know about `Y` is that it is a `MyClass` and it's parents. That means methodI is trying to assign. `UnaryOperatory<ExtI> fn` to `UnaryOperator<? extends MyClass>`. They're not the same thing. But they could be. Which is why

```
methodI(t -> (ExtI) fn.apply((Y) t));
```

works. Your constraints don't say what you're doing is wrong, they just don't guarantee correctness. If you use explicit casts you can "make it work".

Consider this simple class.

```
class Example<T>{

    T apply( T t ){
        return t;
    }
    <U> U identity( U u){
        return u;
    }
 }

Example<String> ex = new Example();
ex.apply("one");
```

That works because apply works on String.

```
ex.apply(2);
```

Broken because ex is parameterized by a String.

```
ex.identity(2);
```

Works because identity takes the parameter type when it is called.

Comment: Thanks heaps. Almost there, I think I am hitting something. I can see assigning `UnaryOperatory<ExtI>` to `UnaryOperator<? extends MyClass>` surely shouldn't be allowed, and OK that Java interprets it that way for `<Y extends MyClass> void test(UnaryOperator<Y> fn)`. But if we look into `UnaryOperator#apply`, it is defined as `Y apply(Y y)`, which I can't tell the difference from `<X extends MyClass> X identity(X x)`, why Java does not interpret `identity` the same?

Comment: One is at the class/interface level. `Y` has already been defined for apply when you created an instance of the interface. `X` is at the method level and gets assigned when you call identity or assign it as a UnaryOperator with a type which is closer to your example.

Comment: OK, that surely is a difference that I never thought of, and I believe this can be the answer to my question. But why a class/interface level generic parameter is interpreted differently from a method level generic parameter?

Comment: I updated the answer to include an example. They're different because you're telling them to be different. When you specify the generic at the method, you're saying I want this Type to be decided by the code that is going to use the method. It gives you some freedom.

Comment: Here is an example where you have a parameterized type Collection and it has a parameterized method with a different type. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355941/why-collection-toarrayt-doesnt-take-an-e-instead