# How to use Types.isAssignable properly?

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I'm having problems with [`Types.isAssignable()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Types.html#isAssignable%28javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror,%20javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror%29) from annotations processing API. I have this two variables:

```
TypeMirror someType; // with some value
TypeMirror objectType = elementUtils.getTypeElement("java.lang.Object").asType();
```

When I execute `typeUtils.isAssignable(someType, objectType)` it returns `false`.

Why does this happen? Any type could be assigned to an `Object`. What am I misunderstanding?

---

Note: `isAssignable` returns the expected value with this *trick*:

```
TypeElement typeElement = (TypeElement) typeUtils.asElement(someType);
String qualifiedName = typeElement.getQualifiedName().toString();
TypeMirror copy = elementUtils.getTypeElement(qualifiedName).asType();
typeUtils.isAssignable(copy, objectType); // returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

[Types.isAssignable()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter. It returns true if so; otherwise it returns false. If this Class object represents a primitive type, **this method returns true if the specified Class parameter is exactly this Class object; otherwise it returns false**.

Comment: This doesn't explain why a `POJO` class cannot be assigned to `Object`.

Comment: I don't have exact answer,`Class.isAssignableFrom() essentially checks the subtyping relation. "subtype" and "subclass" are two different concepts. ` more detail  refer it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650931/why-object-class-isassignablefromstring-class-true it may help you.